# Python list Merging

Tags: python

I am getting list output like this, I want to make clear separation between lists
so that I can access each list separately how do I do that

```
for Book in rootNode.getBooks():
    CompareTables=[]
    CompareTables.append(Book.getName())
    for Table in Book.getTables():
        CompareTables.append(Table.getName())
    print CompareTables

Output:

['Document', 'A','B','C']
['Document', 'A','B','C','D','E','F']
```

I want output like this:

```
print CompareTables1

Output:

 ['Document', 'A','B','C']

print CompareTables2

 ['Document', 'A','B','C','D','E','F']
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little more? If I understand you, the goal to do the printing after the loop rather than inside the loop, is that right?

Comment: It doesnt matters as now when i am printing CompateTables its giving me different lists, that is ok, but I want to access them by different names as I want to compare elements in them

Comment: Did you make it work yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new list to add your per-book lists to:

```
all_compare_tables = []
for Book in rootNode.getBooks():
    CompareTables=[]
    CompareTables.append(Book.getName())
    for Table in Book.getTables():
        CompareTables.append(Table.getName())
    all_compare_tables.append(CompareTables)

print all_compare_tables[0]
print all_compare_tables[1]

# better yet, loop:

for compare_tables in all_compare_tables:
    print compare_tables
```

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary:

```
all_compare_tables = {}
for i, Book in enumerate(rootNode.getBooks(), 1):
    CompareTables=[]
    CompareTables.append(Book.getName())
    for Table in Book.getTables():
        CompareTables.append(Table.getName())
    all_compare_tables['CompareTables{}'.format(i)] = CompareTables
```

The above example generates keys as `CompareTables1`, `CompareTables2`, etc. but perhaps you had better names in mind.

Printing these then becomes:

```
print all_compare_tables['CompareTables1']
print all_compare_tables['CompareTables2']
```

or loop over the `all_compare_tables.keys()` or `all_compare_tables.values()` sequences.

Comment: [['Document','A','B','C' ]]
[['Document', 'A','B','C','D','E','F']]

Comment: any more help? They still seems to be same, I want to have access them separtely

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: I don't think you executed my code correctly; you seem to have created multiple `all_compare_tables` lists inside of your loop.

Comment: No change its still the same print all_compare_tables['CompareTables1'] gives me both tables

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: and you are using the *exact same code* as in my samples? I very much doubt that you are. Please do *doublecheck* you are not creating the `CompareTables` list outside of the loop, for example.

Comment: I double cross checked it print all_compare_tables['CompareTables1] is still giving me both list

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: Please paste your code into a paste service (such as http://pastie.org) and link it in a comment. You are still reusing te same list somewhere instead of creating a new list every loop.

Comment: And you are certain that that is the code that is run? Can you add a `print "doublecheck"` at a random line in there? You can also add `print CompareTables` inside the loop at the end.

Comment: So what does `print Book.getName(), [t.getName() for t in Book.getTables()]` inside the loop print? *There is nothing in this code that would create multiple lists* unless those values create nested lists.

Comment: and when I am ruuning print all_compare_tables['CompareTables2'] its givimg me key error : 'CompareTables2'

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: I am strongly suspecting you have an indentation issue here. Make sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces, as that could lead to code being executed outside the loop.

Comment: print Book.getName is priting name name  Document Document

Comment: Please use backticks when quoting output; that tells me absolutely *nothing*.

Comment: No change I checked everything

Comment: Sorry, looks like I cannot help you then. I cannot reproduce the problem here.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: Nope. You *cannot* get a newline in the output. You really want to examine your development environment, but I would not trust it if I were you if you really are getting that as the output.

Comment: I don't know its sounding weired to me too! but I pasted exact code and outputs to you

Comment: It seems my value of i is not increasing

Comment: Because If a change value of i from 1 to 2 in loop, it changes the value to Document2, Document 2 in both, any suggestions?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: Did you replace `enumerate()` with another function perhaps?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: or are you running this code multithreaded? Your environment is *not* behaving like standard Python would, making it neigh impossible to help you here.

Comment: No I did't change the Enumerate, I am using metagen to access XML files in reader(python)

Comment: The problem was in my framework, I fixed it now you code is working! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, a `dict` is made for such cases:

```
CompareTables = {}
for Book in rootNode.getBooks():
    book_name = Book.getName()
    CompareTables[book_name] = []
    for Table in Book.getTables():
        CompareTables[book_name].append(Table.getName())
    print CompareTables
```

Here your 2 books seem to have same title `Document`, so you can use an index to differentiate them:

```
CompareTables = {}
for i, Book in enumerate(rootNode.getBooks(), 1):
    book_name = Book.getName() + str(i)
    CompareTables[book_name] = []
    for Table in Book.getTables():
        CompareTables[book_name].append(Table.getName())
    print CompareTables
```

Comment: {'Document1': ['A','B','C']}
{'Document1': ['A','B','C','D','E','F']}                 STILL I CAN'T DISTINGUIS THEM

Comment: @Martijn: this is why I added the 2nd part ! Are you sure you read my post entirely ?

Comment: @Emmanuel: Print CompareTables is giving me both list, I want to make them separately accessible by two different list name

Comment: It seems my value of i is not increasing, every time it prints Document1 for both files

Comment: Because If a change value of i from 1 to 2 in loop, it changes the value to Document2, Document 2 in both, any suggestions?

Comment: @Martijn: do you see it edited ? No, because it wasn't. I can send you a screen capture if you want :-)

Comment: @Emmanuel: it was edited in the grace period; edits within 5 minutes of posting or a later initial edit are merged in the edit history.

Comment: @Abhishek : this is strange, can you please show what `print [(i, Book) for (i, Book) in enumerate(rootNode.getBooks(), 1)]` ? `i` should increase, this is the way `enumerate` works.

Comment: its giving me [(1, <rootNode_api.sBook instance at 0x6e37b90>)], pritning same line 5-6 times with only instance adress change

Comment: Really strange: `enumerate` increases its index for each item found. What is the nature of `rootNode` ?